# A second getpwuid call appears to overwrite old value

Tags: c, linux, rhel, setuid, getpwuid

Here's a small C program that prints (well, supposed to print) the real and effective IDs of a process when the file has the setuid flag set. In this program, when I call `getpwuid` a second time (L.No 38), it tends to overwrite the value of the variable `realUserName` that was obtained in L.No 24. I'm unable to explain this behavior. Is this the expected behavior and why? I'm trying this in a Linux box (RHEL 2.6.18-371.1.2.el5).

```
  1 /* Filename: test.c
  2  * Notes:
  3  * 1] ./test owned by user cadmn (userID: 3585)
  4  * 2] ./test run by user pmn (4471)
  5  * 3] ./test has the setuid bit switched-on.
  6  */
  7 #include <stdio.h>
  8 #include <pwd.h>
  9 #include <sys/types.h>
 10 #include <unistd.h>
 11 int main()
 12 {
 13
 14     uid_t realId, effectiveId;
 15     struct passwd *realUser, *effUser;
 16
 17     realId = getuid(); // realId = 4471
 18     effectiveId = geteuid(); //effectiveId = 3585
 19
 20     printf("Real ID is %i and Effective ID is %i\n", (int)realId, (int)effectiveId);
 21     //prints 4472 and 3585, respectively
 22
 23     realUser = getpwuid(realId);
 24     char *realUserName = realUser->pw_name; //realUserName = pmn
 25
 26     printf("Real ID (name) at this point is %s\n", realUserName);
 27     // prints pmn.
 28
 29     /*
 30      *********************************************************
 31      *                                                       *
 32      *    everything works as expected up to this point      *
 33      *                                                       *
 34      *********************************************************
 35      */
 36
 37     // The value obtained from this call is not used anywhere in this program
 38     effUser = getpwuid(effectiveId);
 39     printf("\nCalled getpwuid with the effectiveId\n\n");
 40
 41     printf("Real ID is %i and Effective ID is %i\n", (int)realId, (int)effectiveId);
 42     //prints 4472 and 3585, respectively
 43
 44     printf("Real ID (name) at this point is %s.\n", realUserName);
 45     // Expect to still see 'pmn' printed; though see 'cadmn' as the output!
 46     // Why does this happen?
 47
 48     return 0;
 49 }
 50
```

Output:

```
pmn@rhel /tmp/temp > id pmn
uid=4471(pmn) gid=1000(nusers) groups=1000(nusers)
pmn@rhel /tmp/temp >

pmn@rhel /tmp/temp > id cadmn
uid=3585(cadmn) gid=401(cusers) groups=401(cusers)
pmn@rhel /tmp/temp >

pmn@rhel /tmp/temp > ls -l ./test
-r-sr-xr-x 1 cadmn cusers 9377 Dec 24 19:48 ./test
pmn@rhel /tmp/temp >

pmn@rhel /tmp/temp > ./test
Real ID is 4471 and Effective ID is 3585
Real ID (name) at this point is pmn

Called getpwuid with the effectiveId

Real ID is 4471 and Effective ID is 3585
Real ID (name) at this point is cadmn.
pmn@rhel /tmp/temp >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you observe is the expected one.

The structure referenced by the return value of `getpwuid()` is defined statically internal to the latter, so it is expected to be filled (and with this overwritten) for each call to `getpwuid()`.

This line

```
char * realUserName = realUser->pw_name;
```

just stores a reference to a value held by this statically internal structure. This value is also overwritten if  the statically internal structure is overwritten by the next call to `getpwuid()`.

To get around this there are two possibilities:

- Use te reentrant version of `getpwuid()` which is [`getpwuid_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html). To be able to use it, add

  ```
  #define _POSIX_SOURCE
  ```

  before the very 1<sup>st</sup> `#include` statement in your program's sources.
- Create copy of the members you need, `pw_name`in this case. The can be achieved by for example doing:

  ```
  char * realUserName = strdup(realUser->pw_name);
  ```

  Be awre that `realUserName` is now pointing to dynamically allocated memory, which needs to be `free()`ed by the program itself if not need anymore. To do so call

  ```
  free(realUserName);
  ```

Comment: getpwuid_r was too wordy for me (too many parameters :)) so I tried the second option which did the trick. Thanks for the help. BTW, what do you mean by "_The structure referenced [...] is_ statically internal _to the latter?_"

Comment: @pmn: I added the missing "*defined*". **Reading** the specification for `getpwuid_r()` might enlight you why this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find the specification for this? This one: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpwuid.html ?

Comment: @pmn: Yes. Or a even recent version here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html